# Writing a CV in Latex

Tags: latex

I am trying to write a CV in Latex, but now I am stuck. Since I want to learn Latex, I don't really want to just use a template.

I am thinking about one page divided in to columns/minipages:

- Left column: an image + contact information etc.
- Right Column: Education, experience, volunteer work etc.

Tried minipages and columns, but the image is destroying the whole format... Tried to use parts from templates, which worked fine, i.e. secsty etc. See example under.

Not a specific question, but hope someone has a good idea for how to make something out of this idea :)

Example:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=10mm, top=10mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}{1pt}}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}}

%Document
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[250mm]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics{image.png}
Date of birth:
Phone:
Email:
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[250mm]{0.65\linewidth}
\part*{Name}
\section*{EDUCATION}
\section*{EXPERIENCE}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are several CV packages on ctan https://ctan.org/search?phrase=cv Test them and if there is a feature that you cannot implement, ask a specific question. But your present question is too broad and insufficiently focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is great to see that you don't simply copy one of the existing templates, but want to learn some latex instead.

Some comments about your code:

- if you want the minipages besides each other to emulate columns, their combined sum has to be equal or smaller than the linewidth. In your example 0.4+0.65= 1.05, so they won't fit in one line. In fact I would make them a bit smaller and add a `\hfill` between to get a bit of space between them
- to make sure each minipage is only as wide as you specified, I would add the `[width=\linewidth]` option to the image. This will automatically scale the image correctly
- if you want both minipages in one line, don't leave an empty line between them. In latex and empty line in the source code is interpreted as a paragraph break, thus forcing your second minipage in a new line
- To get a better vertical alignment of the image, I would remove the optional height argument from the minipage and let tex determine how high your minipages are and add the options `[T]` and `[b]` respectively to determine the vertical alignment
- this is more a design question: at the moment your page geometry is highly asymmetric. You can visualise this by adding `showframe` to your geometry options, e.g. `\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=10mm, top=10mm,showframe}`. Are you sure this is a good choice for a CV?

---

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=10mm, top=10mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-10pt}{1pt}}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}}

%Document
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[T]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}

Date of birth:

Phone:

Email:
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
\part*{Name}
\section*{EDUCATION}
\section*{EXPERIENCE}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]